# Filtering JComboBoxes and generic types

Tags: java, generics, reflection, filtering, jcombobox

Let's say I have a JComboBox with SomeObject1< T > in it, and a JComboBox with SomeObject2< T > in it. 
Is it possible in Java, if I select for example a SomeObject< String > in the comboBox 1, to filter the comboBox 2 to only displays the SomeObject2< String > in it, using reflection or whatever ? Thanks